# Heaven and Hell in Buddhism

Tags: traditions, heavens, hells

I need to understand some concept about Buddhism.

Does Buddhists believe on after live of Paradise and Hell? What are the belief of Buddhists regarding this?

Comment: I think the important thing is that these words describe a state of mind. Everything beyond is just concept (Like there is no such thing as 'this life' in ultimate reality). Because actually you don't know what happens when you die.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there are [31 realms of existences](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/ptf/dhamma/sagga/loka.html).

From top to bottom:

- 4 immaterial realms
- 16 fine material realms
- 6 heavens
- human realm
- Asura hell
- ghost hell
- animal hell
- Niraya(hells of unimaginable suffering)

Life spans of each realm varies, but there are no ever lasting places of existence. Yes, you will keep being born in these places again and again according to your Karma, every time you die, until you attain Nibbana and end the process.

Comment: So according to your reply I understood, there are heaven and hell. We will keep being born in these place again and again. So even If I go to heaven, I will die there and born again. Is it?

Comment: Correct! But there are many heavens and hells. Not just one. Once your life span runs out or if it's cut short, you will die and be born again

Comment: so, once someone born in a heaven, he will enjoy the life. As long as there are no sin in the heaven, he will keep being born in heaven until nibana right?

Comment: No! Gods do commit sins, just like humans. And they can easily become ignorant due to long life and refined pleasures. It's easy for them to fall to lower realms. In comparison, It's harder for hell beings to come up as the natural tendency of most beings is to do wrong.

Comment: Then the God would born in the earth or hell if he commits sin?

Comment: Yes, if the sin is strong enough to cut off his life, he will be born in a hell. There are some gods who die, just because they got angry. You can't become a human with a sin. A good Karma should come forward to give a human life.

Comment: that's weired !!

Answer (score 1):

Some Buddhist scriptures state by doing good you can go to heaven & by doing evil you can go to hell.

Also, if you love the Buddha, you can go to heaven.

> 'These beings — who were endowed with bad conduct of body, speech &
>   mind, who reviled noble ones, held wrong views and undertook actions
>   under the influence of wrong views — with the break-up of the body,
>   after death, have re-appeared in the plane of deprivation, the bad
>   destination, the lower realms, in **hell**. But these beings — who were
>   endowed with good conduct of body, speech & mind, who did not revile
>   noble ones, who held right views and undertook actions under the
>   influence of right views — with the break-up of the body, after death,
>   have re-appeared in the good destinations, in the **heaven**ly world.'
>
> Bhaya-bherava Sutta

~~~

> 306. The liar goes to **hell**; also he who, having done (wrong), says, "I did not do it." Men of base actions both, on departing they share the
>        same destiny in the other world.
> 307. There are many evil characters and uncontrolled men wearing the saffron robe. These wicked men will be born in **hell** because of their
>        evil deeds.
> 308. It would be better to swallow a red-hot iron ball, blazing like fire, than as an immoral and uncontrolled monk to eat the alms of the
>        people.
> 309. Four misfortunes befall the reckless man who consorts with another's wife: acquisition of demerit, disturbed sleep, ill-repute
>        and rebirth in **hell**.
>
> Nirayavagga: Hell

~~~

> 47. Monks, in this Teaching that is so well proclaimed by me & is plain, open, explicit & free of patchwork, those who have simply
>       faith in me, simply love for me, are all destined for **heaven**.
>
> Alagaddupama Sutta

Answer (score 1):

There are different realms described but I don't think it needs to be so complicated. The point is that you create your own hell or your own heaven, for example; if you hit your head against a wall on purpose, would you not be in pain? Would this be hell? Another example; if you lie and cheat, people you have hurt may come after you and hurt you, wouldn't this be hell?

Alternative, if you are careful you can avoid hitting your head, wouldn't that be great? And if you don't lie and cheat, then you don't need to worry about people taking revenge, wouldn't not having to worry about anything be heaven?

You create your own reality, even right now in this lifetime.